# HTML Atributo condicional

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Necesito hacer esto en HTML:

```
<option *ngFor="let country of countries" selected="${country.name === 'Brasil' ? 'true':'false'}">{{country.name}}</option>
```

Pero no está funcionando.

¿Podrían orientarme?

Comment: Hola este foro es totalmente en español si quisieras ayuda asi como lo pides creo que deberias ir a https://stackoverflow.com/ ese esta en ingles, de no ser asi puedes tratar de explicar lo que necesitas en español para tratar de ayudarte

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Estás en Stack Overflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada o dirígete a la [comunidad en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías probar con esto:

```html
<option *ngFor="let country of countries" [selected]="country.name === 'Brasil'">{{country.name}}</option>
```